# mysql, select two tables, then merge results

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables.

```
table_A
  A    
  ---- 
  a    
  b    
  c    
  d    


table_B
  B    
  ---- 
  1    
  2
```

and want to select it like below

```
  A      B   
  ----  ---- 
  a      1
  b      2
  c     null
  d     null
```

How can I make such a select.
Do I need procedure? or just need 'join syntax'?
Please help me.

Comment: which  relation you have between the two tables?

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Without a column to specify ordering, you cannot guarantee the results.

Comment: Displaying unrelated data in a newspaper style is usually not done with SQL. Get your data in two queries instead and use your programming language to display the data as desired in your grid, HTML table or whatever it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have [mysql with 8.0.2](http://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-2-introducing-window-functions/) and higher then you can use window functions

```
select t.a, tb.b
from
(
  select a, count(*) over (order by a) rn
  from table_a
) t
left join table_b tb on t.rn = tb.b
```

[demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=57f0a2cf229f522271a188fa0146e19f)

**RESULT**

```
a   b
-------
a   1
b   2
c   null
d   null
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL tables represent *unordered* results.  You can put the values side-by-side (as I will show), but without a column specifying the ordering, the order within each list is arbitrary.

```
select max(a) as a, max(b) as b
from ((select (@rna := @rna + 1) as rn, a, null as b
       from a cross join (select @rna := 0) params
      ) union all
      (select (@rnb := @rnb + 1) as rn, null as a, b
       from b cross join (select @rnb := 0) params
      ) 
     ) ab
group by rn;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so in a select statement using join.

An example might be:

```
SELECT a.value, b.value
FROM a
  left outer join b on a.id = b.id;
```

But this requires that you have primary / foreign keys that relate the rows in the separate tables.

Your tables will need to look something like this:

```
table_A   
  --id--value-- 
   123     a    
   214     b    
   567     c    
   455     d    


table_B   
  --id--value-- 
   123     1    
   214     2
```